# Read date from JObject JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to dynamically read json. I have everything working but date. So I have

```
                    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                    data.location= (obj["duration"].Value<double>());
                    data.deviceID = (obj["deviceID"].Value<string>());
                    data.reason= (obj["reason"].Value<string>());
                    data.id= (obj["id"].Value<string>());

                    // data.startTime=(obj["startTime"].Value<DateTime>());
                    string start = (string)obj.SelectToken("startTime");
```

In quickwatch the date looks like

[image]
so I tried date time with no luck. If i can get the string value I found a different stackoverflow post that used this for a solution. However I can not read it in a good manner yet

```
        private DateTime TryParseIso8601(string s)
    {
        string format = s.EndsWith("Z") ? "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" : "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz";
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date);
        return date;

    }
```

Per comment, the exception generate by

```
data.startTime = (obj["startTime"].Value<DateTime>());
```

is [image]

Comment: So what happens with that code? I would expect you to be able to just cast the token to `DateTime`, with the default settings. If you could provide a [mcve] we could experiment with, that would really help.

Comment: could you also add your Json and answer which Daisy mentioned above ?

Comment: The token should be `startTime.$date` as `startTime` returns a object based on your provided screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `SelectToken` to read the date.

```
var jToken = obj.SelectToken("startTime.$date");
var date = jToken.Value<DateTime>();
```

Check this live fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/9o4FJt

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = "{\"startTime\" : { \"$date\" : \"2018-03-19T19:38:02.929Z\"}  }";

        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);

        Console.WriteLine(jObj);

        var jToken = jObj.SelectToken("startTime.$date");



        Console.WriteLine(jToken.Value<DateTime>());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiddle has been overwritten with something unrelated :-(